# Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.cypher.mapParallel2`: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error polling, timeout of 10 seconds reached

Tags: neo4j, parallel-processing, neo4j-apoc

I am trying to count the number of relationships (c:Cell)-[:EXPRSSED_IN]->(g:Gene) by using the query:

```
CYPHER runtime=pipelined
MATCH (c:Cell)-[r:EXPRESSED_IN]->(g:Gene)
WHERE c.id >= 0 AND c.id < 6000
RETURN count(*) AS count;
```

The query executed successfully. However, it was slower than what I expected. It took around 6 seconds to count a list of around 45 million rows. I'm not sure if it's the "common case". Despite that, I want to speed it up furthermore by using parallel processing. Below is the query that I'm trying to execute:

```
MATCH (c:Cell)
WHERE c.id >= 0 AND c.id < 6000
WITH COLLECT(c) AS cells
CALL apoc.cypher.mapParallel2("MATCH (_)-[:EXPRESSED_IN]->(g:Gene) RETURN _.id AS cell_id, g.id AS gene_id",
    {parallel:True, batchSize:1000, concurrency:20},
    cells,
    20) yield value
return COUNT(*) as count;
```

It gives me the error `Failed to invoke procedure "apoc.cypher.mapParallel2": Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error polling, timeout of 10 seconds reached.` My guess is that it has something to do with the sockets and ports as the server will probably open some sockets to communicate with its workers.

Could anyone provide me a solution? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1:** I use neo4j enterprise version 4.1.3

**UPDATE 2:** My query is actually incorrect. I have fixed it and it executed successfully. However, now it's taking even more time than without doing any parallel processing

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in only the number of relationships of your nodes you can use relationship store with the following query:

```
MATCH (c:Cell)
WHERE c.id >= 0 AND c.id < 6000
RETURN sum(size( (c)-[:EXPRESSED_IN]->()) as count
```